# setting intent on an array item onclick

Tags: java

Guys I would really like to open an `Activity` with `Intent` from a `Searchview`.
I don't know how to go about here is my code

```
String dataArr[] = {
    "Kiambu county","Kisumu county","Kitui county",
    "Laikipia county","Lamu county","Makongeni county",
    "Meru county","Mombasa county","Muranga county",
    "Nairobi county","Nakuru county","Narok county",
    "kajiado county","kiambu county","Uansingishu county"
};
ArrayAdapter<String> newsAdapter = 
    new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, dataArr);
mSearchAutoComplete.setAdapter(newsAdapter);

// Listen to search view item on click event.
mSearchAutoComplete.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        if (i==0){
            Intent intent=new Intent(County.this,Kiambu.class);
        }
    }
});

// Below event is triggered when submit search query.
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(County.this).create();
        alertDialog.setMessage("Search keyword is " + query);
        alertDialog.show();
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

I would really appreciate help such that when i search for a word and click on it it takes me to another class

Comment: all the post i have read are about a listview only this is about auto complete searchview

Comment: you are missing `startActivity()` call after defining intent

Comment: @vivek mishra i have it i just didi put half code

Comment: from your current code it will only open new activity when you click on 1st item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

startActivity(intent);
after defining intent.
You onClick work only if your i == 0 (first element)
And you don't need i == 0.
Get you element from ArrayAdapter which controls elements and pass into Intent

```
 String art = arrayAdapter.get(i);
if (art != null) {
  //here intent
}
```

And County.this,Kiambu.class... What is it?

Comment: Need more explanation.

Answer (score -1):

thenks guys but the problem was with my device thanks for the replies